# ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Tuple{} are not callable

Tags: variables, julia

I have never used Julia and I am following a tutorial.  I have reached an instruction that are written below.  When I tried the Lon3D, Lat3D,Depth3D =LonLatDepthGrid(lon,lat,depth)  I got and error saying  **ERROR: UndefVarError: LonLatDepthGrid not defined**
I tried creating the variable using *LonLatDepthGrid =()*
I ran the Lon3d.... command again then got the following error * MethodError: objects of type Tuple{} are not callable*
What am I missing????
THanks
K

Here is the order in which I am defining variables:

```
lat = ncread("APVC.ANT+RF.Ward.2014_kmps.nc","latitude")
lon = ncread("APVC.ANT+RF.Ward.2014_kmps.nc","longitude") 
depth = ncread("APVC.ANT+RF.Ward.2014_kmps.nc","depth")
Vs_3D = ncread("APVC.ANT+RF.Ward.2014_kmps.nc","vs")
depth = -1 .* depth
Lon3D,Lat3D,Depth3D = LonLatDepthGrid(lon, lat, depth);
```

I tried creating the variable using
LonLatDepthGrid =()
I ran the Lon3d.... command again then got the following error * MethodError: objects of type Tuple{} are not callable*
What am I missing????
THanks
K

Comment: I don't have an answer, but wanted to say welcome! 

Comment: it is not possible to answer unless you provide information which tutorial you are following or which library you use.

Answer (score 0):

You created a tuple called `LonLatDepthGrid`:

```
julia> LonLatDepthGrid =()

julia> typeof(LonLatDepthGrid)
Tuple{}
```

But then you tried to use the tuple as a function:

```
julia> LonLatDepthGrid(...)
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Tuple{} are not callable
```

Also, it's difficult to help you further without knowing what the packages you're using...

Answer (score 0):

Please read the Julia documentation about installing packages from their repositories.

GeophysicalModelGenerator.jl needs to be installed:

```
julia> ]add GeophysicalModelGenerator

...

julia> using GeophysicalModelGenerator
```

Now this should compile:

```
Lat         =   1.0:3:10.0;
Lon         =   11.0:4:20.0;
Depth       =   (-20:5:-10)*km;
Lon3D,Lat3D,Depth3D = LonLatDepthGrid(Lon, Lat, Depth);
```